# If $ \det\begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{bmatrix}=-2$, calculate:

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

$$ \det\begin{bmatrix} 2 & -2 & 0\\ c+1 & -1 & 2a \\ d-2 & 2 & 2b \end{bmatrix}$$

After using Gauss Elimination, I get the following equation: $4*b*c-4*a*d$

and then I don't know what to do... Please help! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since :

$$\det\begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{bmatrix}=-2$$

this means that : $$ad - bc = -2$$

Your given result is : $4bc - 4ad = 4(bc-ad)= -4(ad-bc)=-4\cdot (-2) = 8$

Answer (score 2):

$$4bc-4ad=-4(ad-bc)=-4\det\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{bmatrix}=8
$$

Answer (score 1):

You are so close! The determinant condition tells you $ad-bc = -2$, while you have $\det A = 4(bc-ad)$. How does $bc-ad$ relate to $ad-bc$?

Answer (score 0):

Use *multilinearity*:
\begin{align}
&\begin{vmatrix} 2 & -2 & 0\\ c+1 & -1 & 2a \\ d-2 & 2 & 2b \end{vmatrix}=\begin{vmatrix} 2 & -2 & 0\\ c & -1 & 2a \\ d & 2 & 2b \end{vmatrix}+\underbrace{\begin{vmatrix} 2 & -2 & 0\\ 1 & -1 & 2a \\ 2 & 2 & 2b \end{vmatrix}}_{=\,0}=\begin{vmatrix} 2 & 0 & 0\\ c & c-1 & 2a \\ d & d+2 & 2b \end{vmatrix}\\&=4\begin{vmatrix} c-1 & a \\  d+2 & b \end{vmatrix}=4\begin{vmatrix} c & a \\  d & b \end{vmatrix}+4\begin{vmatrix}-1 & a \\2 & b \end{vmatrix}=-4\begin{vmatrix} a & b \\  c & d \end{vmatrix}-4(2a+b)=-4(2a+b-2).
\end{align}